# Spring Cloud Gateway: How to add a filter group to use in multiple groups

Tags: spring, cloud, gateway

Building new API Gateway with spring cloud gateway. Currently experience following challenges.

**Q1:** Looking after functionality to group multiple filters together to form a filter chain and add the filter chain to a route. This avoids copy/paste of multiple filters every Route.

**Q2:** Looking after to apply to filter chain group to multiple URI's in the same route.

**Q3:** Is it possible to do route chaining and conditional route chaining in spring cloud gateway

**Q4:** How to do the Orchestration/aggregation of multiple service responses in spring cloud gateway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the following answers all your questions, but it sure answers some.

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder routeBuilder) {
    return routeBuilder.routes()
            .route("my_route",
                    route -> route
                            .path("/context/my-resources/**")
                            .filters(f -> f
                                    .rewritePath("/context/my-resources/of-some-type/(?<RID>.*)", "/my-resources-of-type-one/${RID}")
                                    .rewritePath("/context/my-resources/of-some-other-type/(?<RID>.*)", "/my-resources-of-type-two/${RID}")
                                    .hystrix(config -> config.setName("fallback name")))
                            .uri("http://localhost:8091")
            )
            .build();
}
```

In this example 3 filters are chained: the first and second filters map URLs and forward path variables to the downstream URLs, while the third filter defines a fallback strategy.